# NetworkPolicy doesn't block all the pods communication

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I need to block pods communication to each other but I failed to do it.
I installed [weave plug-in](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/) on my **Minikube** (v1.21.0), and started two pods in the same namespace:

```
 kubectl run nginx1 --image=nginx -n ns1
 kubectl run nginx2 --image=nginx -n ns2
```

**The pods IPs:**
`nginx1` with IP: `172.17.0.3`
`nginx2` with IP: `172.17.0.4`

I can ping `nginx1` from `nginx2` and vice vesra.
I wanted to try to deny it, so I firstly tried to deny all the network with this network policy:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol1
  namespace: earth
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress: []
  egress: []
EOF
```

I still had ping, so I tried this one too:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: netpol1
  namespace: earth
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 172.17.0.0/16 
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 172.17.0.0/16
EOF
```

I still can ping each pod from within the other pods in the same namespace.
I verified that `weave` is installed:

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-74ff55c5b-2r5z8                   1/1     Running   0          2d3h
etcd-ip-172-31-37-46                      1/1     Running   0          2d3h
kube-apiserver-ip-172-31-37-46            1/1     Running   0          2d3h
kube-controller-manager-ip-172-31-37-46   1/1     Running   0          2d3h
kube-proxy-787pj                          1/1     Running   0          2d3h
kube-scheduler-ip-172-31-37-46            1/1     Running   0          2d3h
storage-provisioner                       1/1     Running   0          2d3h
weave-net-wd52r                           2/2     Running   1          23m
```

I also tried to restart kubelet but I still have access from each pod to the other one.
What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the Egress and Ingress resources, you do not specify the network protcol. In the [kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) you can see that the protocol can be specified too. Your kubernetes cluster defaults your Egress and Ingress resources to a protocol if you do not specify one.

If you block all TCP or UDP networking, you will find that ping still works just fine. This is because ping uses the ICMP network protocol, not TCP or UDP.

The actual configuration you need depends on your networking plugin. I do not know how to configure Weave to block ICMP.
If you were using Calico, their [docs](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/network-policy/policy-rules/icmp-ping) explain how to handle the ICMP protocol.